# Naming a new project with "Sample Professional" but creating with the name "Sample Prof-e-s-s-i-onal" in Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, winrt-xaml, uwp

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015 in my Windows 10, and upon starting a new project with a name succeeded with the word **Professional**, e.g. as with the name *"Sample Professional"*, it is creating with a name *"Sample Prof-e-s-s-i-onal"* instead of *"Sample Professional"*?

Any thought why it's happening? How can I prevent that and what's the right solution for that?

Comment: Any reason for the down vote?

Comment: Strange but I can now create a new project with a name succeeded with the word "Professional", maybe I just copied the word "Professional" from my Vim text editor or from the other website but I'm not sure if that causes the problem.

Comment: You might have different encoding.